# Google BigQuery Share Dataset Access - how can I know who have been given the shared access to these datasets/tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We can share individual dataset access, through this step.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

- Select the dataset
- Share the dataset

We can do this one by one. And we can even share the individual BigQuery table this way.

But how can I know who have been given the shared access to all these datasets/tables of my GCP project?

Instead of go to the each dataset and each table, check "share" link manually?

Thanks!

Comment: have you ever tried using Magnus? If so, you can easily use API Task to collect all the needed stats that exposed in PAIs only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use a python function that shows that information for all datasets.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

client = bigquery.Client()
datasets = list(client.list_datasets())  
project = client.project
print("Datasets in project {}:".format(project))
for dataset in datasets:
    os.system('bq show --project_id {}  {}'.format(project,dataset.dataset_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
bq show --project_id PROJECT DATASET
```